# How to retrieve table row value in Struts2 action

Tags: struts2, struts

I am new to Struts 2 , please help me with the below scenario

I have a table in Jsp using struts2 tag , All I Want to do is to retrieve the selected(checked) table row's value in the action class.

Please let me know how to achieve it .

```
<s:iterator value="listOfDtos" status="stat">
<tr>
<td><s:checkbox name="delete" value="select" /></td>
   <td><s:property value="FirstName"/></td>
   <td><s:property value="LastName"/></td>
   </tr>
   </s:iterator>
   <s:submit id="delete" value="delete"/>
}
```

"`listOfDtos`" is an array list od dto and is set in the action like the below

```
 ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().set("listOfDtos", listOfDtos);
```

Now when the user selects any row to be deleted I want to be able to first of all retrieve this list of dtos in the  Action and iterate them to check which of the dtos have the attribute "select" set to true.  select" is an attribute of type String in the dto.

How can this be done? Also how will the "listOfDtos" be made available in the Action.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i have understood your question properly.but here are few inputs to start with.

There is no need to do  `ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().set("listOfDtos", listOfDtos);` as this will bind your action class with framework tightly.I suggest you to create a property in your action class with name `listOfDtos` as ArrayList and provides its getter and setters, framework will place your array-list in the value-stack for you.

You need to provide some unique values to your check-box based on which you can check in your action class which id has been selected as you can perform any desired operation on the ArrayList based on the ID.

Comment: Hey Umesh Thanks for the reply, I will update back very soon.

Comment: Here is the scenario. First search action is invoked. So here is the place where I can have ArrayList called as the "listOfDtos" with getters and setters. When this search action is executed listOfDtos is populated and the search results jsp iterated through these dtos and displays it. Now the user selects couple of records and clicks a button called delete. The delete button is tied to a separate action called DeleteAction. So now the listOfDtos is not available in this DeleteAction. Even if I again have another listOfDtos defined in DeleteAction , how will those values be populated ?

Comment: @MattPatt: you have few ways to do this.Either create a list in your `DeleteAction` and populate that from the JSP and once list is populated and you have list of selected items can go ahead with list deletion.Other way is to fetch the List in your `DeleteAction` same way you have done it `search action` and go ahead with furthur work